# get_deleted_objects() missing 2 required positional arguments: 'admin_site' and 'using'

Tags: django

When I delete data by xadmin, I got the error that `get_deleted_objects()` missing 2 required positional arguments: 'admin_site' and 'using', Who can help me, thanks a lot

Comment: Please post the *full* traceback...

Comment: Are you sure that xadmin is compatible with the version of django you are using? Seems that there hasn't been new releases of xadmin for a while.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it in my branch and made a pull request, you can reinstall `xadmin` with:

```
pip unsintall xadmin
pip install https://github.com/mymusise/xadmin/archive/django2.zip
```

Or you can reinstall from [sshwsfc/xadmin@django2](https://github.com/sshwsfc/xadmin/tree/django2) later.

Comment: In the above information, I forgot to explain that I am using the source installation method using xadmin. I use the branch called 'django2'